# Can I have a complex target condition for a device configuration in azure IoTHub?

Tags: azure, iot, azure-iot-hub

In the Azure IoT Hub, you can add configuration for IoT devices. This configuration includes a "Target Condition" to determine to which devices the configuration will be applied. Some target condition examples might be based on the tags (`tags.environment = production`) or based on the device id (`deviceId = iot-device-demo`).

I want to know if I am able to set the target configuration, based on a specific deviceId ending, (for example: `deviceId.endsWith(-demo)`). What is the correct syntaxis for this? Am I limited to an equality comparison '='?

Comment: I'm having the same problem with IoTHub. Have you found any alternatives that have worked for you? 
I was hoping to use `ARRAY_CONTAINS(tags.propertyList, '1')` to target any Devices that may have '1' in the array on the tags.propertyList field. 
The following query works just fine when querying for Devices, but not in the Target Condition for Device Configuration.



`tags.environment = 'test' AND ARRAY_CONTAINS(tags.[[group]],'1')`

Comment: @StevenvanderMerwe Kinda, for IoTEdge devices an initial global config would be applied to all devices. The config includes a ConfigReslverModule of sorts to run any logic to determine the device "type" or "environment" and set those properties in the module twin. The IoTHub will use the module twin to determine which further config to apply to the device. It is not clean but it is a workaround, plus you can have the logic to determine the device type or env in any language. However you need to maintain an extra module which can just not be included in the config specific to a device.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. To work around this limitation, you can add a tag to your device twin. You can add the tag to all the devices that end with `-demo` and create a configuration built on that.